# What do these registry entries for outlook add-in mean?

Tags: outlook, registry, vsto, outlook-addin

I have some add-ins installed for Outlook. And there are entries in the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Addins\UCAddin.LyncAddin.1`, Where `UCAddin.LyncAddin.1` is an entry for my Lync addin.

[image]

What do these registry entries mean for the add-in. How does it affect the working of the add-in.

Since I am also developing outlook add-in, I want to know if I need to worry about these registry entries.

**Edit**

This is not in particular about the lync add-in. It's about all the add-ins. Since there is a registry entry with my add-in, I want to know what is the significance of these registry entries.

Comment: Your question is not related to software development so you are probably better served to post your question in an IT Pro related forum

Comment: This is very mich related to software development. This is not some IT Pro question. Please analyse before downvoting.

Comment: Your question, as currently is, just asks about the specification (what is stored by the Add-in developer) of the specific Lync Add-in. There is nothing development related to that and furthermore, besides the fact that it is stored in the Add-ins section of Outlook not even related to VSTO. Basic COM Add-ins can be stored here as well. It is the mechanism Office uses to expose Add-ins to Office. VSTO is not needed to make use of it. The fact that an Add-in is listed here does not mean you will be affected by it.

Comment: But what are those entries? If I am developing an add-in, I need to know what is the significance of those entries. For eg, The registry entry in the HKCU hive for LoadBehavior indicates how the add-on is loaded.

Comment: As Add-in developer I can add any arbitrary entry to whatever I like to the registry key if I want to store my own information to the add-in entry. There is no need anyone else but myself knows about the added information. LoadBehavior is one of the defined specifications as well as some others (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) The entries added to the add-in in your question are not related to the VSTO specification and most likely only of use by the component itself.

Comment: To be more clear, I created my own Addin and installed. Then there were entries here related to my Addin. But I am not storing any data in my Addin. So these registry entries have to be generated by outlook or office internally. I wanted to know why are they being created

Comment: How did you install the Add-in (InstallShield, ClickOnce, other)? BTW, the question has been asked before, no answer though: http://superuser.com/questions/1026560/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-reg-binary-keys-for-office-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

I ran procmon and took a look at the stack associated with reading/writing those keys. Those numbered reg keys are used internally by Outlook and not something you need to mess with. You can safely ignore their existence.

Comment: Can you provide any references?

Comment: Nope - what we use those registry keys for is not publicly documented. But for what you asked, the answer is you don't need to worry about them.